# using geocoder with myLocationOverlay

Tags: android, geocoding, mylocationoverlay

i try to get the current zip code from the longitude and latitude which MyLocationOverlay delivers and set this to a EditView on my Activity.

The Activity crashs when i try to get the longitude and latitude from MyLocationOverlay.

Whats wrong with this code?

Regards,
float

LogCat output: http://codepaste.net/vs6itk 
Line 59 is the following line:

```
 double currentLatitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();
```

Here is my Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.partner_suche);

    final EditText tView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPLZ);
    final MapView mView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mView.getController().setZoom(14);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mView.getOverlays();

    myLocationOverlay = new MyCustomLocationOverlay(this, mView);
    mapOverlays.add(myLocationOverlay);
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        }
    });

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    double currentLatitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();
    double currentLongitute = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6();

    try 
    {
        List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitute, 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) 
        {
            tView.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }
}
```

EDIT:
I created a LocationListener to get my current location. Now the part crashes where i try to run gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); I can't read the Exception? :/

```
LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
    String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            updateWithNewLocation(location);
            } 

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
            updateWithNewLocation(null);
            }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras){ }
        };

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, locationListener);

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
    final EditText tView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPLZ);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    if (location != null) {
        try 
        {
            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                    tView.setText(address.getPostalCode());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the log cat output.

Comment: here is the logcat output: http://codepaste.net/vs6itk Line 59 is the following line:         double currentLatitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an emulator API level 8 or 9, and getting the exception:

java.io.IOException: Service not Available

then it is a known bug, see [service not available](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816)

It works OK on real devices and emulator level 7 though. ( You should probably put a trap on addresses being null too, though this won't make the geocoder work!)

Comment: Samsung Galaxy Tab uses Android 2.2 Froyo (API Level 8) and on this device my app crashs too. Unfortunatly i don't know how to get the log from this device...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the location being returned from

```
myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation()
```

or

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

is NULL.  Likely due to your application not yet having received a location fix, and having no previously saved locations.

Try moving the code block where you do the geocoding into your runnable that runs after receiving a fix.  Like this:

```
myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Location loc = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
        if (loc != null) {
            mView.getController().animateTo(loc);
            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            double currentLatitude = loc.getLatitudeE6();
            double currentLongitute = loc.getLongitudeE6();

            try 
            {
                List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitute, 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                {
                    tView.setText(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation() returns a Geopoint. If i try to declare a Geocoder instance in the new runable(){} part im getting a compiler error "The constructor Geocoder(new Runnable(){}, Locale) is undefined"

Comment: Sorry about that.  The Geocoder constructor wants a context, and when you put it in the runnable, "this" no longer refers to your activity.  Try using getApplicationContext() instead.

Comment: thanks. Now it crashes when i try to get the Location. List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitute, 1); On the Emulator and the Samsung Galaxy Tab too.